# regex replace slash or ignore

Tags: regex, replace

I have particular text that looks like the following:

```
CLIA ID:  
Rapid Strep Test w/reflex culture
```

My regex to grab "Rapid Strep Test w/reflex culture"
looks like this

```
(?<=CLIA\s*ID:\s*\n)[a-zA-Z_0-9 /]{1,30}
```

here is my problem, my program actually grabs the text and then using the text it renames the input file with what it grabbed. The bad thing is the sending system cannot NOT send the / and as we all know I cannot name a file with a slash in it in Windows. Is there a way for me to grab the first 30 characters and if it finds / anywhere to replace it with a space?? I would even be ok with a REGEX where it finds the / to keep it in the capture, but exclude it in the output so end results would be something like

```
Rapid Strep Test wreflex culture
```

(30 characters max as i have of course). but ultimately i would like it to output

```
Rapid Strep Test w reflex culture
```

any thoughts please?

Comment: Which language? Python/Perl/sed? You might be able to just pass over the expression with a `re.Replace("/", " ")` to convert the '/' character to the space, and then parse as normal.

Comment: it is the .net framework so i am not sure what it is based on. It has a regex parser built in to it. I have been using Expresso to do all of my testing. my developer of the program said the regex is actually used just for matching and not replacing, so anywway i can use something to just ignore it?

Comment: Classic case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you are asking about your solution when you should be asking about your problem. Take a step back - you don't want to use regex here. Once you reach that conclusion you will be able to solve this.

Comment: unfortunately i have to use regex bc that is how the developer programmed to capture info out of a PDF. i would have to ask him to reprogram if i dont use regex. i tried using
(?<=CLIA\s*ID:\s*\n)[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]{1,30}(?:/)[a-zA-Z_0-9 ]{1,30}

but that isnt working either bc it still is coming back in the results set even though i said to find it, but ignore it

Answer (score 0):

"In theoretical computer science and formal language theory, a regular expression (abbreviated regex or regexp) is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings, or string matching" - [Wikipedia, Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

I don't think that doing this using just Regex is possible.

If you are using .NET, you can use the [String replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to replace all occurrences of a substring with a different substring.  This is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small try for a solution in JavaScript using a callback function. The same approach is possible in many other languages

```
text.replace(
    /CLIA\s*ID:\s*\n([\w\s]{1,30}).*/,
    function(s) {return s.replace('/', ' ');}
);
```